# Android How to keep text in EditText when taping outside?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

When I type in an EditText and the tap in another part of the screen, the text in the EditText disappears (as the keyboard does when it closes/hides).

The EditText is a password input and is currently being displayed in an `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder passwordInputDialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.CustomAlertDialog);
TextInputLayout passwordInputLayout           = new TextInputLayout(MainActivity.this);
passwordInputInflater                         = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.password_input, null);

passwordInputDialog
    .setCustomTitle(passwordInputTextView)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setView(passwordInputLayout)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", onPositiveAlertDialogClick())
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", onNegativeAlertDialogClick());

final AlertDialog passwordInputShownDialog = passwordInputDialog.show();
final EditText enteredPassword = passwordInputInflater.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
```

The EditText has attached a `addTextChangedListener` event, which is able to perform well any other operation:

```
enteredPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable enteredText) {
        ...
        enteredPassword.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        enteredPassword.setText(enteredText);
        enteredPassword.setSelection(enteredText.length());
        enteredPassword.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
});
```

The thing is if there's something I'm doing wrong, or is the default behavior of an EditText within a Dialog "when leaving the input".

How can I do in order to "preserve" the text that has been entered in the EditText right after taping outside of this?

---

This is what I get when I try to set the text of the EditText on the afterTextChanged function:

```
2019-11-24 20:20:46.795 20941-20954/com.example.map2 I/om.example.map: Background concurrent copying GC freed 135477(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 9MB/18MB, paused 79us total 113.470ms
2019-11-24 20:20:54.553 20941-20954/com.example.map2 I/om.example.map: Background concurrent copying GC freed 136023(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 10MB/21MB, paused 89us total 128.803ms
2019-11-24 20:21:03.751 20941-20954/com.example.map2 I/om.example.map: Background concurrent copying GC freed 137630(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 12MB/25MB, paused 108us total 162.638ms
2019-11-24 20:21:13.794 20941-20954/com.example.map2 I/om.example.map: Background concurrent copying GC freed 137787(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 14MB/28MB, paused 110us total 153.423ms
2019-11-24 20:21:24.617 20941-20954/com.example.map2 I/om.example.map: Background concurrent copying GC freed 137118(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 16MB/32MB, paused 101us total 181.131ms
```

It freezes the application and I had to kill it.

I understood and realized that what I need isn't to do that. As I wanna save what the user writes in the SharedPreferences to display them again so the user doesn't have to type the things more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by closing alertDialog, all of the data inside will be lost.
you can prevent to close alertDialog by :

```
passwordInputDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

or you can save the last value inside of alertDialog and bring it back by showing again. (not recommended)

Comment: Hi Siavoosh, thanks for your time. This solves one part of the problem in some way, but still I'm able to leave the focus and lose what I've typed.

Comment: I understood this is the closest I can go. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

> To Answer your question, the editText is not the one disappearing!
>   It's the dialog and since the dialog is the one hosting the editText, onCancle of the dialog simply takes away the editText also if that's exactly what you're doing.
>
> > **Note: Pay attention to the comments in the code below.**
>
> **First Observation:**

```
enteredPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable enteredText) {
        ...
        enteredPassword.removeTextChangedListener(this); /* why this? when you will still add it back immediately below? */
        enteredPassword.setText(enteredText); /*Change to enteredText.toString() because enteredText is an interface and you need to point to the method toString to get the character array inside it.*/
        enteredPassword.setSelection(enteredText.length()); /*Not sure why you're using this either */
        enteredPassword.addTextChangedListener(this); /*why this? when you're already listening?*/
    }
});
```

> **This can replace what you currently have about the enterPassword above:**

```
enteredPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable enteredText) {
    enteredPassword.setText(enteredText.toString()); /* although this is actually weird! in the sense that enteredPassword already has the text and yet, you're still assigning it texts back to itself, I mean enteredPassword.setText(enteredPassword.getText().toString() is equivalent to enteredText.toString())*/
    }
});
```

> **Also:**
>   Since you said the editText is in the dialog, then you should not be seeing the editText if the Dialog actually dismisses, Well, I guess the dialog did not dismiss and on the same dialog you're trying to do something else and when the focus change from the editText to another View on the Dialog, then the texts in the EditText for enter password is gone? if Yes: Then you actually don't need the TextChange listeners if all you need is the texts, simple create a variable to store the text and use as you want.
>
> **Finally:**
>   My question is what are you trying to do in particular? don't be scare to ask more elaborative questions, you just need to be specific.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. The `enteredPassword.removeTextChangedListener ` is because when modifying the EditText from that function itself, the application enters in an infinite loop. Can't explain really how, I'm fairly new to Android and Java.

Comment: @sab I think you need to take more time to review your code top down, meanwhile infinite loop in what context? on typing in the editText or ? I will suggest you simply remove these two lines: enteredPassword.removeTextChangedListener(); enteredPassword.addTextChangedListener(this);
Because at the point you're putting those, you're already listening and no need to remove or re-add. also, is the issue resolved now? if yes, mind posting the answer if any of ours answers did not match.?

Comment: Sorry Whales, the problem still is unresolved. I added `passwordInputDialog.setCancelable ` as Siavoosh suggested, but still I'm loosing what I type when leaving the focus from the input.

Comment: @sab  can you open as a new question specific to the current issue you're facing on this and share the link here so I can follow up?